# How to login with Crypt encryption in login controller

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using `Crypt::` for registration and login. My registration is successful but login is not successful. Please check the code and help me.

```
public function Login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $userdata = array(
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => \Crypt::encrypt($request->password)
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($userdata) {
        echo "success";die();
    } 

    return "Ops! snap! seems like you provide an invalid login credentials";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Originial

You need to use [Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing), not [Encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/encryption).

**Registration**

```
...

$userdata = [
    'email'    => $request->email
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
];

...

// User saved..
```

**Login**

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

if (Auth::attempt($credentials) {
    // It work
}
```

Ref :

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing

---

### Update

> **OP** : I need to Crypt::decrypt to decode the password and send on email. Using hash i couldn't decode it. Thats the reason i need Crypt.

**I really don't recommend it**. That's why we have the "forgot password" feature to create new password.

[Is it secure to store passwords with 2 way encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/174126/12753)

Okay, back to the topic, **How to login with Crypt encryption?**

You need to add `login()` method in `Auth\LoginController` :

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $decrypted = $request->input('password'); 
    $user      = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

    if ($user) {
        if (Crypt::decryptString($user->password) == $decrypted) {
            Auth::login($user);

            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

---

#### WARNING!

> All of Laravel's encrypted values are signed using a message authentication code (MAC) so that their underlying value can not be modified once encrypted.

**You must have the same key. If you change the key (`artisan key:generate`), it means you will not be able to login.**

**I really don't recommend it**.

Comment: I need to Crypt::decrypt to decode the password and send on email. Using hash i couldn't decode it. Thats the reason i need Crypt

Comment: Crypt is working at the time of registration but to login i need a function to login with crypt

Comment: @Sultanjahan Why are you emailing the passwords...?

Comment: Client requriement is to get the hashed pasword and decode and mail it.. So i am using crypt to insert the on regitsration and decode and send on email. Its working but how do i make changes in login controller to login with crypt

Comment: @Sultanjahan How will you protect the encryption key when the attacker gains admin access to the server?

Comment: Client want password on email so what should i do.. as admin approves user then client want the password should send on email.

Comment: The correct course of action when your client wants to email user passwords in the clear is to tell them that they are a moron and that they hired a developer for a reason.  **Do your job.**

Comment: Please provide solutions

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem before.
I used Crypt Encryption because I need to display the password from encrypted to decrypted in laravel blade input element.

I deeply look at laravel references in projects and found a solution.
In default laravel used HASH for encryption, since I used Crypt to Register and Login.
When I try to Login this returns false.
What I did is edited one laravel function located in

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentServiceProvider.php
```

and change this function from these

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
   {
      $plain = $credentials['password'];
    
      return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());

   }
```

to these

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
   {
      $plain = $credentials['password'];
    
      return \Crypt::decrypt($user->getAuthPassword());
   }
```