# Laravel - problem with Crypt::decrypt, wrong syntax in code

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, crypt

I know that my solution is wrong, but can someone help me with correct syntax how decrypt my string and log in ?

Laravel API resived `code` and store encrypted in `Database`

`api route`

```
Route::post('data','DataImport@Insert');
```

`controller`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

function Insert(Request $request)
{
    $user=new User();
     $user->code=Crypt::encrypt($request->input('code'));
    return $user->save();
}
```

`Auth\Controller`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'id_message' => 'required',
        'code' => 'required',
    ]);
   
    $credentials = $request->only('id_message', 'code');
    $decrypted = $request->input('code'); 
    $request->session()->flash('success');

    if ($user=User::where($credentials)->first()) {
        if (\Crypt::decrypt($user->code) == $decrypted) {
            Auth::login($user);
            
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard')->with('success');
        }
    }
    //dd($decrypted);

    return Redirect::back()->with('error');
}
```

`dd($decrypted);`

```
 array:1 [▼
 "code" => "123456"
]
```

decrypted `code` is in correct value. No error in `laravel.log` only message code does not match.

thanks for any help.

(solution with hash, dont help me with this problem)

Comment: if you want a single input from the request you don't use `only` as that always will return an array .. use `input` (also don't use `get`, its not a laravel method) `$code = $request->input('code')` .... it looks like you are trying to compare an array to a single value at the moment, since `$request->only()` returns an array

Comment: @lagbox dont get array after your fix, but still have ````code does not match```` no error in laravel.log. do i have any more errors in code?

Comment: btw, any reason to not use passwords?

Comment: `$decrypted` is an array here. Is the decrypted `$user->code` also an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has same problem. @lagbox help me with incorrect syntax with `input`, and reference link below did final solution:

`replace this:`

```
$credentials = $request->only('id_message', 'sms_code');
```

`to:`

```
$user = User::where('id_message', $request->input('id_message'))->first();
```

and `if` statment to:

```
if ($user) {
    if (\Crypt::decrypt($user->code) == $decrypted) {
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard')->with('success');
        }
    }
    return Redirect::back()->with('error');
}
```

reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50891573/3681759